# Use Where Clause in Neo4J Java API

Tags: neo4j

How can I translate below query to Neo4j's Traversal Framework Java API?

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name="A")
     , m=node:node_auto_index(name="M")
 MATCH p=a-[*]-m
 WHERE ALL(r in RELS(p) WHERE r.value >= 200)
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p) desc limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create your own `Evaluator` class, as this is what does the evaluation from step to step. Read more [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_evaluator).